# Boundary Value of Function Disagrees with Neumann Boundary Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve a time-dependent 2D heat equation with a source, initial specified heat distribution and heat flux loss at the boundary which goes with the temperature difference. Thus far, I've managed to get the prior two parts working but the source term seems to make the derivative at the boundary disagree with the value specified by the Neumann conditions with no error message. My code is shown below.

The mesh I used is as shown below:
[image: Mesh of the different electronic elements in model]

Then some functions are defined to handle the piecewise values of the properties like the source and the heat capacities etc.

```
PropertyFunction[x_, y_, 
   properties_] := (properties[[1]] - properties[[3]])*
    RectPiecewise[x, 
     y, \[CapitalOmega]Resistor] + (properties[[2]] - 
      properties[[3]])*
    RectPiecewise[x, y, \[CapitalOmega]Thermistor] + 
   properties[[3]]*DiskPiecewise[x, y, \[CapitalOmega]Air];
HeatSource[x_, y_, S_] := 
  S*RectPiecewise[x, y, \[CapitalOmega]Resistor] ;
(*Properties are in order of resistor, thermistor, paste*)
```

Then after subsituting the material values, we set up the equation with the variables and parameters.

```
(*Variables and parameters for heat equation*)

vars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 
    PropertyFunction[x, y, ThermConduct]*IdentityMatrix[2],
   "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> PropertyFunction[x, y, VolHeatCapacity],
   "HeatSource" -> HeatSource[x, y, SourceStrength]|>;
```

Then we define the Neumann Boundary Conditions below and plug this into the NDSolveValue to get the solution.

```
(*Defining Neumann Boundary Conditions*)
HeatTransferCoeff = 10000000; (*Made this lower*)
\[CapitalGamma] = 
 HeatTransferValue[{Abs[x] == dist, Abs[y] == dist}, vars, 
  pars, <|"HeatTransferCoefficient" -> HeatTransferCoeff, 
   "AmbientTemperature" -> T0|>]

pde = {{HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == \[CapitalGamma]}, 
   T[0, x, y] == T0};
thermsol2 = 
 Refine[NDSolveValue[pde, 
   T, {x, y} \[Element] PlotMesh, {t, 0.0, 100000}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 10], {Element[T, PositiveReals]}]
```

This produces a reasonable looking solution. However, looking closer at the derivative at the boundary, it's not equal to the value set by the Neumann condition. To compare the two, the Neumann condition has to be divided by the thermal conductivity since it's specified in terms of a heat flux which is proportional to the gradient.

To compare them, the values of the gradients against time were plotted (green is the Neumann one) and then their difference was also plotted.
[image: Value of gradients and their difference against time]
This is a small percent difference but is it a numerical error or human error? I'm just worried it's infringing on the accuracy of my results. The code to produce these graphs is below:

```
Xderivplus[t_, x_] := Derivative[0, 1, 0][thermsol2][t, x, 0]
NeuVal[k_] := (\[CapitalGamma][[1]]/0.17) /. {T -> thermsol2, 
   x -> dist, y -> 0, t -> k}
time = 30;
Show[Plot[Xderivplus[t], {t, 0, time}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[NeuVal[t], {t, 0, time}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All]]
Plot[(Xderivplus[t] - NeuVal[t]), {t, 0, time}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The gradients differ by a noticeable amount at the boundary. As I mentioned earlier, this is not an issue without the source term and for a given domain, one can predict where the offset will be shifted to. I've read the documentation for the NeumannBoundaryValue (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) and it seems like the source term should be treated as their "f" parameter and effectively ignored as part of the boundary conditions where it is zero anyway. Is this something to do with the mesh not being fine enough around the boundary?

Any help or insight on specifying the NeumannValues would be greatly appreciated, thanks!